# Link in popup window does not close the window?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this bit of html code, but when I click the link, it does not close:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
   </head>
<body>
    <h2>Members Only</h2>
    <p>You must be a member.</p>
    <p>Please Sign In or Create an Account.</p>
    <a href="javascript: self.close ()">Close this Window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just removed the spaces and it works well :

```
<a href="javascript:self.close()">Close this Window</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Popups suck, use a [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal.html) instead, especially for something as simple as a notification.

That being said, try this:

```
 <a href="javascript:window.close()">Close this Window</a>
```

Comment: Yes, I blindly copied the poster's script, spaces included. Duh. Scarlet Garden has it right.